# Battery terminal voltage and internal resistance

Tags: batteries, internal-resistance

I read somewhere that a battery reaches the end of its useful life because of an increase in its internal resistance rather than a decrease in its open-circuit terminal voltage. Is it correct?

Comment: ‘A battery’? Different chemistries do different things. What battery are you wanting to know about?

Comment: I want to know if this behaviour is true of batteries in general. However, if you want a specific type, how about lead-acid batteries?

Comment: ‘Battery university’ has a good run down on the popular chemistries. Maybe visit there and come back with a specific question.

Comment: As already commented it depends on the chemistry… primary lithium for example works forever and simply just die when discharged

Answer (score 1):

In general the open circuit voltage of a battery does not always give a direct indication of its State of Charge (SoC) and/or State of Health (SoH) and/or any other factors impacting its End of Life (EoL). If the battery is "young and healthy" then the voltage alone may give better indication of SoC then when it is sick or near EoL.

Increased internal resistance is one symptom of lower State of Charge and/or reduced State of Health. This means more energy is dissipated inside the battery as waste heat and less power transfers to the load in a given application. The EoL analysis depends on both the battery and the application.

Answer (score 0):

The 'State of Charge' (SoC) of a battery is its available capacity, while in use, as a percentage of that available when it is fully charged.

The open-circuit voltage of a typical 12V AGM lead-acid battery would be between 10.8V at 30% capacity and 13.8V at 100% capacity.

It could be safely discharged to about 10.8V and restored to its original state with a recharge.

The 'State of Health' (SoH) of a battery is the maximum capacity to which it could be charged, as a percentage of that to which a fresh battery could.

Increased internal impedance could be an indicator of either a low SoC or a low SoH.

The relationship between internal impedance and SoC is shown below
(Courtesy of *Batteries Panasonic VRLA Handbook Professionals https://actec.dk/media/documents/A337A624823A.pdf*).

[image]